# Difference in Use between pwd and $PWD

Tags: command-line

To print current/present working directory **environment variable** `$PWD` and **command** `pwd` are available. So, What is difference in usage of both? or What should be chose for specific purpose?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That depends on what you're doing. First of all, `$PWD` is an environment variable and `pwd` is a shell builtin or an actual binary:

```
$ type -a pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
pwd is /bin/pwd
```

Now, the bash builtin will simply print the current value of `$PWD` unless you use the `-P` flag. As explained in `help pwd`:

```
pwd: pwd [-LP]
Print the name of the current working directory.

Options:
  -L    print the value of $PWD if it names the current working
    directory
  -P    print the physical directory, without any symbolic links

By default, `pwd' behaves as if `-L' were specified.
```

The `pwd` binary, on the other hand, gets the current directory through the `getcwd(3)` system call which returns the same value as `readlink -f /proc/self/cwd`. To illustrate, try moving into a directory that is a link to another one:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jun  4 11:22 foo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon    4 Jun  4 11:22 linktofoo -> foo/
$ cd linktofoo
$ echo $PWD
/home/terdon/foo/linktofoo
$ pwd
/home/terdon/foo/linktofoo
$ /bin/pwd
/home/terdon/foo/foo
```

So, in conclusion, on GNU systems (such as Ubuntu), `pwd` and `echo $PWD` are equivalent unless you use the `-P` option but `/bin/pwd` is different and behaves like `pwd -P`.

Comment: One difference is that using $PWD when available will avoid forking a subcomand like echo or pwd.  This makes it advantageous for performance and program tracing.

Answer (score 4):

Both will return the same result if you use them without options for all working directories, including when in symbolic links.

However, from `man pwd`:

```
-P, --physical
    avoid all symlinks
```

This would mean executing `pwd -P` when in symbolic links which point to some other directories will print the path to the original directory.

As an example, if you have a symbolic link `/var/run` that points to `/run` and you are currently in `/var/run/` directory, executing

```
echo $PWD
```

will return:

```
/var/run
```

and will be the same for `pwd`. However, if you execute:

```
pwd -P
```

will return

```
/run
```

Thus, it depends which path you require: the actual path without symbolic links or the present directory ignoring the symbolic links. The only difference between between `pwd -P` and `echo $PWD` is when there are symbolic links.